# VBA delete rows when there is blanks or 1 or "Safe" but keep safe emply cell having 1 or "Safe" using formulla

Tags: vba

I want delete blank cell from range of `T2:T200` by keeping data safe if cell empty by `""` or `1 (=if(b2<>"",1,"")` or `(=if(b2<>"","safe","")` without using loop

```
Sub remove_blankrows()
Range("T2:T200").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code? What have you tried so far, to fix the issue? Please have a read of https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask then come back and edit your question. As it stands, it's no use to anyone.

Comment: @Spikey_richie Thanks for correction of my question which helpful to get solution

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a formula-based approach in VBA. To delete rows containing blank cells in the range T2:T200 while keeping cells with the value 1 or "Safe" intact:

```
Sub remove_blankrows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Replace "Sheet1" with your actual sheet name
    
    ' Apply the formula to identify rows to delete
    ws.Range("U2:U200").Formula = "=IF(OR(T2="""", T2=1, T2=""Safe""), """", ""Delete"")"
    
    ' Filter and delete rows based on the formula result
    ws.Range("U2:U200").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Delete"
    ws.Range("U2:U200").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    ' Clear the temporary formula column
    ws.Range("U2:U200").ClearContents
End Sub
```

1. The range U2:U200 is used as a temporary column to apply a formula that marks rows for deletion based on the criteria.
2. The formula checks if the corresponding cell in column T is blank (""), 1, or "Safe" and returns an empty string (""), indicating that the row should be deleted.
3. After applying the formula, the code sets up an AutoFilter on the temporary column and filters for rows marked as "Delete."
4. It then deletes the visible rows and clears the temporary formula column.
5. Finally, the AutoFilter is turned off.

Comment: Thanks @Safdar Mirza

The solution given by you working perfectly, which I stuck to apply condition.

You Solve the issue.